# data not shown on listview

Tags: android

I have two processes running when the application runs. when the process "loaddata" finished, the result is stored into the database using sqlite. When that process next "Workoffline" will be run, it is responsible for loading the data from the database and shows a listview of application. but my problem here is, when the application is finished, my listview is empty , i run the application to reload again, the new data appear . Can you help me.(I have to find out on google can use android synchronized, in order to process "LoadData" run finished then last run process Workoffline, but I do not know what to do!!)

source code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invoice);
     doTimerTask();
    }
 // load dữ liệu lên listview
public void loaddatalistview()
{
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(Invoice.this, codeInvoiceArray
            .toArray(new String[codeInvoiceArray.size()]), nameArray
            .toArray(new String[nameArray.size()]), phonenumberArray
            .toArray(new String[phonenumberArray.size()]), addressArray
            .toArray(new String[addressArray.size()])));
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        // xử lý sự kiện khi chọn item trên listview
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent j = new Intent(Invoice.this, Menu_Main.class);

            // lấy thông tin thông qua vị trí của item được chọn
            String url = urlArray.get(position);
            String address = addressArray.get(position);
            String mahoadon = codeInvoiceArray.get(position);
            String phone = phonenumberArray.get(position);

            // chuyển thông tin này qua bên phần MENU
            j.putExtra("url", url);
            j.putExtra("address", address);
            j.putExtra("mahoadon", mahoadon);
            j.putExtra("phone", phone);
            j.putExtra("ID", IDDelivery);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
}

// Ứng dụng sẽ hoạt động offline với data được lưu trong database khi thiết
// bị không có
// kết nối mạng
public void workoffline()
{
    clearArray();
    try {
        mDb.openDB();
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.getAllInvoice(IDDelivery);
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                codeInvoiceArray.add(mCursor.getString(1));
                nameArray.add(mCursor.getString(2));
                phonenumberArray.add(mCursor.getString(3));
                addressArray.add(mCursor.getString(4));
                urlArray.add(mCursor.getString(5));

            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            loaddatalistview();
        }
        mDb.closeDB();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

// lấy dữ liệu từ server về thiết bị
public void loaddata()
{

    String sampleURL = SERVICE_URL + "/monthlytarget.php";
    CallUrl wst = new CallUrl(CallUrl.GET_TASK, this, "Lấy thông tin hóa đơn...", 1, IDDelivery);
    wst.execute(new String[] {
            sampleURL
    });

    // Hiển thị thông tin nhận được lên listview

}

// kiểm tra thiết bị có kết nối mạng hay không?
// nếu có thiết bị sẽ làm việc online
// nếu không thiết bị sẽ chuyển sang hoạt động offline
public void testNetwork()
{
    // Kiểm tra kết nối đến server
    TestConnectionNew test = new TestConnectionNew();
    try {
        String recieve = test.execute("http://longvansolution.tk/monthlytarget.php").get();
        if (recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("true") && isNetworkAvailable() == true)
        {
            ***loaddata();
            workoffline();***
        }
        else if (recieve.equalsIgnoreCase("false") || isNetworkAvailable() == false)
        {
            String mess = "Không thể kết nối đến server hoặc thiết bị chưa có kết nối mạng!";
            Toast.makeText(Invoice.this, mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            workoffline();
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// thực hiện load data từ server về theo thời gian định sẵn
public void doTimerTask() {
    TimerTask mTimerTask;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    testNetwork();
                    Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
                }
            });
        }
    };
    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    t.schedule(mTimerTask, 500, 300000); //
}
```